# Change Api level android

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement `ViewOutlineProvider` in my project for set a shadow in my tab, but the logcat said me to change API level version to 21. (my min API version is 15) Are you advice this?
Thanks!

Comment: ViewOutlineProvider only support api >=21

Answer (score 0):

That's because **ViewOutlineProvider** support API>21, you can use `if` statement to apply this feature for devices with an API higher that 21 :

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
     // set shadow ....
}
```